# Lacunary polynomials, sparse interpolation and uniqueness in $F_q$

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I am currently studying lacunary polynomials in finite fields and trying to understand a basic concept.

When we do dense interpolation using a classical method like Lagrange interpolation or Newton's interpolation, we may expect a dense polynomial of degree $d \le n$ for a set of $n+1$ points i.e., a polynomial of the form:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{d} a_k x^{k}, x_d \ne 0$$

In other words, we expect $n$ or less non-constant terms in $f(x)$. This is true of dense interpolation over finite fields such as $\mathbb{F}_q$.

A [lacunary polynomial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.5685.pdf) (also called sparse polynomial or fewnomial) is a polynomial where
the number of its terms is considered fixed, while the degrees and coefficients of its terms
may vary. For example we can write

$$f(x) = a_1 x^{d_1} + . . . + a_l x^{d_{l}}$$

for a lacunary polynomial with at most $l$ terms, with no control whatsoever on the actual value of the degrees $d_i$ and the coefficients $a_i$. (Sparse interpolation methods are given in the linked article and references within).

> [image]

My understanding is that by using a sparse interpolation algorithm for lacunary polynomials, we can obtain an interpolation of $f(x)$ with fewer than $n$ non-constant terms. Then, by using Fermat's Little Theorem, we can reduce degree $d_i$ of terms with $d_i > q$. Therefore, $\forall i, d_i < q$.

**Questions:**

1. Is it true that if we built a blackbox for $n+1$ datapoints using Lagrange or Newton interpolation over in $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $n < q$ and then used that as a blackbox for sparse interpolation of a lacunary polynomial (as many of the sparse interpolation methods seem to require one), we would get a different sparse polynomial?
2. Does this mean that the sparse polynomials obtained are not unique in $\mathbb{F}_q$? How does this reconcile with the [Theorem on Uniqueness of Interpolating Polynomial (See Theorem 4.1 in linked notes)](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ren105/cs314/Chapter4_CS314.pdf)?

Comment: Can you unaccept the answer? The argument I had in mind doesn't actually work. Weird sparse interpolating polynomials do not contradict uniqueness of the interpolating polynomial in the sense of your second link, because they could have degree larger than $n$ in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ has $q$ elements. Degree $d$ of $f$ interpolated from $n$ points where $n < q$. There must be polynomials of degree in the range $[n+1, q-1]$ that interpolate the same points as $f$, some of which may be lacunary. That is what prompted the question.

Comment: Yes, I think we agree on that. I don't think that's what the linked paper is doing, though.

Comment: I think I got it. The flaw in my thinking is that $d_i >q$ for some lacunary polynomial obtained through sparse interpolation. While that may be true, a Fermat reduction would send $d_i$ less than $q$. Even if this $d_i > n$, it still doesn't violate the polynomial uniqueness theorem, because that is only about uniqueness of polynomials of degree $\le n$ for a set of $n+1$ points.

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that by using a sparse interpolation algorithm for lacunary polynomials, we can obtain an interpolation of $f(x)$ with fewer than $n$ non-constant terms.

<strike>This is impossible; you cannot expect to do better than $n$ non-constant terms in general. This is because for $n + 1$ points the vector space of possible inputs is $(n+1)$-dimensional, so the vector space of interpolating polynomials must also be at least $(n+1)$-dimensional to be able to match it.</strike>

**Edit:** Ah, sorry, there's a mistake in this argument. Here I am assuming that the degrees are fixed ahead of time. This argument doesn't apply if the degrees are allowed to depend on the points.

> Is it true that if we built a blackbox for $n+1$ datapoints using Lagrange or Newton interpolation over in $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $n < q$ and then used that as a blackbox for sparse interpolation of a lacunary polynomial (as many of the sparse interpolation methods seem to require one), we would get a different sparse polynomial?

I don't know what sparse interpolation method you have in mind, and I also don't know what you mean by "a different sparse polynomial" - different from what?

It is true, over any field including finite fields, that there is a unique interpolating polynomial of degree $\le n$ if we interpolate at $n + 1$ distinct points. If instead you consider sparse interpolating polynomials of degree $> n$ there is no reason to expect uniqueness, again over any field.

(At least, that was my original interpretation of your question. But I don't think the linked paper is doing this; it looks like the point is to write down an algorithm for interpolation which has the property that it finds a sparse representation when one exists, with a runtime depending on the size of such a sparse representation. But the degree is still $n$, I think.)